# insertion in database not happening instead no error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite

There;s no error in any of the java class as per android studio,but insertion of data is not happening.

My Register_Page.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register__page);
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
        Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
        Phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_phone);
        City = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_city);
        DOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_dob);

        helper = new no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter(this);


    }

    public void addUser(View view) {
        RadioGroup radio_Group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        int radioButtonID = radio_Group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) 
        radio_Group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
        Gender = (String) radioButton.getText();
        String t1 = Name.getText().toString();
        String t3 = Pass.getText().toString();
        String t2 = Email.getText().toString();
        String t5 = DOB.getText().toString();
        String t6 = Phone.getText().toString();
        String t7 = City.getText().toString();
        String t4 = Gender;
        if (t1.isEmpty() || t2.isEmpty() || t3.isEmpty() || t4.isEmpty() || 
        t5.isEmpty() || t6.isEmpty() || t7.isEmpty()) {


  no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(getApplicationContext(), 
  "Enter Required Fields");
        } else {
            long id = helper.insertData(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7);
            if (id <= 0) {

  no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(getApplicationContext(), 
  "Insertion Unsuccessful");
                Name.setText("");
                Pass.setText("");
                Email.setText("");
                DOB.setText("");
                Phone.setText("");
                City.setText("");
            } else {

   no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(getApplicationContext(), 
   "Insertion Successful");
                Name.setText("");
                Pass.setText("");
                Email.setText("");
                DOB.setText("");
                Phone.setText("");
                City.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my myDBHelper.java is as follows:

```
 r

package no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox;




    public long insertData(String name, String email,String pass,String 
    gender,String dob,String phone ,String city)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase dbb = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.MyPASSWORD, pass);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.EMAIL,email);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.DOB,dob);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.GENDER,gender);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.PHONE,phone);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.CITY,city);
        long id = dbb.insert(myDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null , contentValues);
        return id;
    }
    static class myDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";    // 
        Database Name
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "myTable";   // Table Name
        private static final int DATABASE_Version = 1;    // Database 
        Version
        private static final String UID="_id";     // Column I (Primary Key)
        private static final String NAME = "Name";    //Column II
        private static final String MyPASSWORD= "Password";// Column III
        private static final String EMAIL = "Email-id";//Column IV
        private static final String GENDER="Gender";
        private static final String CITY="City";
        private static final String DOB="DOB";
        private static final String PHONE="Phone No.";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE 
        "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+
                UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                NAME+" TEXT, "+
                EMAIL+ " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                MyPASSWORD+" TEXT, "+
                GENDER+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                DOB+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                PHONE+" INTEGER NOT NULL, "+
                CITY+" TEXT );";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 
        "+TABLE_NAME;
        private Context context;

        public myDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_Version);
            this.context=context;
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            try {

                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            } catch (Exception e) {

      no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(context,""+e);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
        newVersion) {
            try {

   no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(context,"OnUpgrade");
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            }catch (Exception e) {

   no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(context,""+e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Register_page.xml is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="no.nodicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Register_Page">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView_phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText_name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.36"
            android:text="Register Here"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#3333ff"
            android:textSize="28dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="viewdata"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70sp"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:text="Name :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="160sp"
            android:text="Email-id :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190sp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Email-id"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_pass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:hint="Enter Password"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_dob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="450sp"
            android:text="Date of Birth :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_dob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Date of Birth"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="540sp"
            android:text="Phone No. :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="570sp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Phone No."
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="630sp"
            android:text="City :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="660sp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your City"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340sp"
            android:text="Gender :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_register"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="720dp"
            android:background="#3368ff"
            android:onClick="addUser"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="340sp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton_male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Male"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton_female"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Female"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton_other"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Other"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I am not getting any errors but the data is not getting inserted.. Its always displaying "Insertion Unsuccessful".

Can someone please tell me where is the problem??

Comment: Maybe you could cut off unnecessary code and give the smallest part that still shows your problem

Comment: There are lots of problems in your code, and you're hiding some of them with the `catch` blocks.

Comment: How do i rectify them ??

Comment: I have removed the try and catch block but its still not inserting.